# How to make Grunt catch npm build task error and fail the task?

Tags: npm, gruntjs

Hello we have a Gruntfile.js configured for our project, it contains the following information
(for demo purpose I deleted many other unrelated contents).

```js
// ...

// Define the configuration for all the tasks
grunt.initConfig({

    // Project settings
    project: appConfig,


    concurrent: {
        options: {
            stderr: true,
            stdout: true,
            failOnError: true
        },

        webpackDevImagmin: ['run:webpackDev'],
    },


    run: {
        options: {
            stderr: true,
            stdout: true,
            failOnError: true
        },
        webpackDev: {
            cmd: 'npm',
            args: [
                'run',
                'build:dev'
            ],
            options: {
                stderr: true,
                stdout: true,
                failOnError: true
            }
        }
    },


});

grunt.registerTask('buildInternal:app', [
    'concurrent:webpackDevImagmin',
]);
```

In our project we deleted some files on purpose to make the npm task fail. But when we do the grunt command, we saw something like

> ```
> ERROR in ./app/public/modules/PartnershipsCtrl.js
>     Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'our/services/OurResource' in /code/our/app/public/modules/partnerships/controllers
>     @ ./app/public/modules/partnerships/controllers/PartnershipsCtrl.js 9:4-53
>
> Done, without errors.
> ```

My theory is that the npm error is NOT returning false for the task, my question is how can I make it return false on error and make the grunt Task fail?

Comment: Possibly related to `grunt-concurrent`'s issue [#47](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-concurrent/issues/47) - although the issue is flagged as _"closed"_ I cannot see any reference to it being fixed in the [commit](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-concurrent/commits/master) history.

Comment: @RobC I tried to not use the current, but only register the "run:webpackDev" task, still same thing.

Comment: Perhaps try utilizing the `exec` key instead e.g. `webpackDev: { exec: 'npm run build:dev', options: { ... } }`